# Как перейти на более старую версию react js

Tags: reactjs

Нужно перейти на старую версию реакта . Как это можно реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл вариант .

- сгенерить реакт-приложение с "текущей" версией
- удалить node_modules
- отредактировать package.json, указав нужные версии

  "react": "^17.0.1",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
  "react-scripts": "4.0.3",

-запустить npm i